# ORACLE - How to fetch all matched & unmatched data from multiple same structured table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have three table **CIS_GROUP,CUSTOMER,CUSTOMER_TEMP** with data.
My Query objective are following:

**1)** Data fetch from *CUSTOMER_TEMP* when same customer exist in *CUSTOMER* table.
**2)** Data fetch from *CUSTOMER_TEMP* when customer exist only in *CUSTOMER_TEMP* table.
**2)** Data fetch from *CUSTOMER* when customer exist only in *CUSTOMER* table.

Where table script & insert scripts are following

```
CREATE TABLE ABABILFE.CIS_GROUP 
 (ID         NUMBER
  ,GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(100)
 )
 /
CREATE TABLE ABABILFE.CUSTOMER 
 (ID         NUMBER
  ,GROUP_ID   NUMBER
  ,CUST_NAME  VARCHAR2(100)
  ,ADDRESS    VARCHAR2(200)
  ,PHONE      VARCHAR2(20)
  ,EMAIL      VARCHAR2(50)
 )
 /
CREATE TABLE ABABILFE.CUSTOMER_TEMP 
 (ID         NUMBER
  ,GROUP_ID   NUMBER
  ,CUST_NAME  VARCHAR2(100)
  ,ADDRESS    VARCHAR2(200)
  ,PHONE      VARCHAR2(20)
  ,EMAIL      VARCHAR2(50)
 )
```

**Insert Script**

```
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into CIS_GROUP
 (ID,GROUP_NAME)
Values
 (1,'Albert');
Insert into CIS_GROUP
 (ID,GROUP_NAME)
Values
 (2,'Eric');
COMMIT;  
-------------------------------------------
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into CUSTOMER
 (ID,CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (1,'Aston','NewYork','0011','aston@gmail.com');
Insert into CUSTOMER
 (ID,GROUP_ID,CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (2,1,'Albert','Canada','0022',NULL);
Insert into CUSTOMER
 (ID,GROUP_ID, CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (3,1,'Bob','Canada',NULL,'bob123@gmail.com');
Insert into CUSTOMER
 (ID,GROUP_ID,CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (4,1,'Charles','Canada',NULL,'charles@gmail.com');
COMMIT;
-------------------------------------------  
SET DEFINE OFF;
Insert into CUSTOMER_TEMP
 (ID,GROUP_ID, CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (3, 1,'Bob','Canada','0023','bob@yahoo.com');
Insert into CUSTOMER_TEMP
 (ID,GROUP_ID, CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (5,2,'Don','London','123','don@hotmail.com');
Insert into CUSTOMER_TEMP
 (ID,GROUP_ID,CUST_NAME,ADDRESS,PHONE,EMAIL)
Values
 (6,2,'Eric','London',null,'eric@gmail.com');
COMMIT;
```

**Table Data**

```
CIS_GROUP Table Data

| ID |GROUP_NAME |
| -- | --------- |
| 1  | Albert    |
| 2  | Eric      |

                     CUSTOMER Table Data

| ID | GROUP_ID |   NAME   | ADDRESS   | PHONE |       EMAIL      |
| ---| ---------| ---------| --------- | ----- | ---------------- |
|  1 |          | Aston    | New York  | 0011  |aston@gmail.com   |
|  2 |    1     | Albert   | Canada    | 0022  |                  |
|  3 |    1     | Bob      | Canada    |       |bob123@gmail.com  |
|  4 |    1     | Charles  | Canada    |       |charles@gmail.com |


                    CUSTOMER_TEMP Table Data

| ID | GROUP_ID |   NAME   | ADDRESS   | PHONE |       EMAIL      |
| ---| ---------| ---------| --------- | ----- | ---------------- |
|  3 |    1     | Bob      | Canada    | 0023  |  bob@yahoo.com   |
|  5 |    2     | Don      | London    | 123   |  don@hotmail.com |
|  6 |    2     | Eric     | London    |       |  eric@gmail.com  |
```

I write following query for my desired result

```
SELECT * FROM

(
 SELECT CUSTOMER_TEMP.id
       ,GROUP_ID
       ,cust_name
       ,address
       ,phone
       ,email
 FROM CIS_GROUP,CUSTOMER_TEMP 
WHERE CIS_GROUP.ID = CUSTOMER_TEMP.GROUP_ID
  AND CIS_GROUP.ID = :PID
)TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT CUSTOMER.id
        ,GROUP_ID
        ,cust_name
        ,address
        ,phone
        ,email
   FROM CIS_GROUP,CUSTOMER
  WHERE CIS_GROUP.ID = CUSTOMER.GROUP_ID
    AND CIS_GROUP.ID = :PID
    AND CUSTOMER.ID NOT IN (SELECT CUSTOMER_TEMP.id
                        FROM ABABILFE.CUSTOMER_TEMP)

  )TABLE2 
  ORDER BY 1
```

**Query Result/Desired Result**

```
          My Desire Result (When parameter(:PID) value is 1)

| ID | GROUP_ID |   NAME   | ADDRESS   | PHONE |       EMAIL      |
| ---| ---------| ---------| --------- | ----- | ---------------- |
|  2 |    1     | Albert   | Canada    | 0022  |                  |
|  3 |    1     | Bob      | Canada    | 0023  |  bob@yahoo.com   |
|  4 |    1     | Charles  | Canada    |       | charles@gmail.com|


           My Desire Result (When parameter(:PID) value is 2)

| ID | GROUP_ID |   NAME   | ADDRESS   | PHONE |       EMAIL      |
| ---| ---------| ---------| --------- | ----- | ---------------- |
|  5 |    2     |    Don   | London    |  123  | don@hotmail.com  |
|  6 |    2     |    Eric  | London    |       |  eric@gmail.com  |
```

how can i write this query more efficient/optimize way?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `CTE`:

```
with t as (select id, cust_name, address, phone, email 
             from customer_temp 
             where group_id = 1)
select * from t
union all
select id, cust_name, address, phone, email from customer 
  where group_id = 1 
    and not exists (select 1 from t where id = customer.id)
```

or rank rows, giving second table priority:

```
select id, cust_name, address, phone, email
  from (
    select rank() over (partition by id order by src) rnk, c.*
      from (
         select 1 src, id, cust_name, address, phone, email 
           from customer_temp where group_id = 1
         union all 
         select 2 src, id, cust_name, address, phone, email 
           from customer where group_id = 1) c )
  where rnk = 1 order by id
```

Both queries produced desired result. There are minor errors in `insert`s you provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot & your reply matched with my desired result.Is there any way to fetched my desire data with single query?

Answer (score 0):

The table CIS_GROUP can be removed because:

- This table is not being selected
- This table is not necessary to filter by group_id, the tables custumer and custumer_temp alredy have a field that can be used for this purpose.

Instead of "union all" with a "not in" in second query, you can use a full outer join, joining by customer id with NVL function to get data from the right table. The first parameter of the NVL defines which table is the main data source.

The final query looks like this:

```
SELECT NVL(CT.id, C.ID) AS ID
      ,NVL(CT.GROUP_ID, C.GROUP_ID) AS GROUP_ID
      ,NVL(CT.cust_name, C.CUST_NAME) AS CUST_NAME
      ,NVL(CT.address, C.ADDRESS) AS ADDRESS
      ,NVL(CT.phone, C.PHONE) AS PHONE
      ,NVL(CT.email, C.EMAIL) AS EMAIL
FROM CUSTOMER C 
FULL OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_TEMP CT ON C.ID = CT.ID
WHERE (CT.GROUP_ID = :PID OR C.GROUP_ID = :PID)
```

This version has a better execution plan. You can try here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae766/16/0)

*EDIT: The previous version did not meet the requirements of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback & Query.Actually your query doesn't fulfill my desired result (When parameter(:PID) value is 1),where Customer(Bob) retrieve two times by your query.But I wants it must be single row which is in both table and only from CUSTOMER_TEMP table.

Comment: I changed the answer and now it's ok, please look again.